# EF core update after migration fails due to nullable type change to enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EF core 2.2.1 and I'm stuck with the following error when I update to the latest migration:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CountryCode', table
>   'context.dbo.User'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE
>   fails. The statement has been terminated.

The message is clear and due to the change on the entity, before the migration it was:

```
public class RegistrationUser : IHaveId, ISearchable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? CountryCode { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

then the type of CountryCode changed to an enum (CountryCode)

```
public class RegistrationUser : IHaveId, ISearchable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public CountryCode CountryCode { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

The entity configuration was not changed even if I tried to set a default value for the enum (still the same error as above):

```
public class UserConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(250);
        builder.Property(e => e.Password).HasMaxLength(250);
        builder.Property(e => e.FirstName).HasMaxLength(100);
        builder.Property(e => e.LastName).HasMaxLength(100);
        builder.Property(e => e.CountryCode).HasDefaultValue(CountryCode.Unknown);
        // other configurations
    }
}
```

The migration is added but the related update fails with this command in the Package Manager Console

> dotnet ef database update

The question is how to properly change this type, having in the generated table a not nullable column with default value (the one configured in EF core EntityTypeConfiguration)

Comment: Most likely you have some rows with CountryCode null, not you changed it to Enum which in fact is a non-null integer.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Yes! You are correct. Problem can be solved by making `public CountryCode? CountryCode { get; set; }`

Comment: @SirwanAfifi that was exactly the case, thank you

Comment: @TanvirArjel it worked, it's so evident now... thank you

Comment: Can I post it answer please?@refex